# How to add custom button on facebook comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I would like to know about the feasiblity of customizing facebook comments as follows:

1. Is possible to create a custom button near to Comment box? eg: Create a new button called "Create" near to "Like", "Replay" and "Share"
2. This button must be visible to facebook page admin in each and every comments.
3. We would like to call a web services if the facebook page admin click the "Create" botton.

Kindly let me know about several possible methods to acheive this.

Best Regards,

Sujan

Answer (score 0):

No, it isn't possible. You can't change the behavior of FB widget, but you can write own comment system with login via FB.

Answer (score 0):

No if this is a standard comment from your users.  When users post from inside your app to their wall (e.g. requesting friends to join them in the app) there can be an extra button (e.g. Enter App).

The main option you would have is to create your own commenting system which links to your facebook users accounts.